# snmptrapd logging error- couldn't open udp:162 -- errno 98 ("Address already in use")

Tags: net-snmp, snmptrapd

I am trying to receive a trap generated by a cisco router on my VM- Ubuntu 14.04. I can do a snmwalk so I guess snmp is working fine but I am not able to receive the traps generated by router on my VM.

```
a@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/snmpd restart
 * Restarting network management services:                                                                                                                                                                   
a@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/snmpd status 
 * snmpd is running
 * snmptrapd is running
```

Here is what I have inside files-

/etc/default/snmpd-

```
export MIBS=
SNMPDRUN=yes
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid -c /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf'
TRAPDRUN=yes
# snmptrapd options (use syslog).
TRAPDOPTS='-n -On -t -Lsd -p /var/run/snmptrapd.pid'
```

/etc/snmp/-

snmpd.conf-

```
rocommunity public
```

snmptrapd.conf-

```
disableAuthorization yes
```

snmp.conf-

```
mibs:
```

The command I am running for viewing the traps on VM-

```
a@ubuntu:/etc/snmp$ sudo snmptrapd -f -Lo -c snmptrapd.conf
couldn't open udp:162 -- errno 98 ("Address already in use")
```

I am confused since the port is being used by snmptrap itself-

```
a@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/services|grep 162
snmp-trap   162/tcp     snmptrap    # Traps for SNMP
snmp-trap   162/udp     snmptrap
a@ubuntu:~$ sudo netstat -lnp| grep 162     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:162             0.0.0.0:*                           6216/snmptrapd  
a@ubuntu:~$ ps -ef | grep snmptrapd
root       6216   2076  0 10:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/snmptrapd -Lsd -p /var/run/snmptrapd.pid
a    6493   2667  0 11:47 pts/8    00:00:00 grep --color=auto snmptrapd
```

Generating a trap from windows using SnmpTrapGen.exe leads to the same error.

Is there any way of solving this issue? I have googled a lot and stuck on this for days, any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Ok the issue is resolved now. I killed the 6216 process and it worked. I had tried it earlier too but my router's config was incorrect, once corrected, the traps were there on stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Port 162 can listen only with an application. If you get this error , you have an app already running which listens port 162 , those can be snmptrapd service or your own application for snmp traps. You should close one of the applications.